# How to add JS confirm to dynamicly created button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, php-5.3

My app's generating href dynamicly. How to add JS confirm onClick?
So far I've tried this one:

```
echo'<a type="button" onClick="return confirm("Are you sure?")" 
class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$this->articleId.'" >Delete</a>';
```

And it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: Expand a little on "it doesn't work".  Does it throw an error? If so, what error? Does it do something unexpected? Do nothing at all?  Providing a little more detail will go a long way in getting the friendly, neighbourhood web experts to give you a hand.

Comment: Why are you using the `return` in the `onclick` attribute? Try it without that...

Comment: @Kalmino It's just goes to href, doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @BubbleHacker I've tried without return, same result :( Just goes straight to href link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the `"` is breaking the your code:

```
onClick="return confirm("Are you sure?")"
```

That line actually splits up in to three:

```
onClick="return confirm(" //Ends here because the code is from " -> "
Are you sure? //This is nothing to the code and cannot be run
")" //This is another string
```

And so the correct way to do it would be the following:

```
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember about this :)

Comment: Anytime! happy coding! =]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo'<a type="button" onClick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"
class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$this->articleId.'" >Delete</a>';>';
```